# Arg to replace seltf with default generic type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a generic type with 3 template inputs:

```
function run<TA = 1, TB = 2, TC = 3>() {
  // code omitted
}
```

In reality, the type definitions are much larger:

```
function run<
  TA = 1, 
  TB = Really<ComplexType, TA, DontWantToTypeThisOverAndOver>, 
  TC = AlsoComplexType<...>
>() {
  // code omitted
}
```

---

*Issue:* In some cases, I want to modify the third argument but not the second.  **Is that possible?** (eg:)

```
// what I want to do
run<_, _, MySpecialType>();


// what I'm currently stuck doing
run<
  MyBaseType, 
  Really<ComplexType, MyBaseType, DontWantToTypeThisOverAndOver>, 
  MySpecialType
>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an ugly solution:  Create extra implementations which will map to the same function but with different generics accessible:

```
function run<
  TA = 1, 
  TB = Really<ComplexType, TA, DontWantToTypeThisOverAndOver>, 
  TC = AlsoComplexType<...>
>() {
  // code omitted
}


// switch second and third argument
function runArgsInverted<
  TA = 1, 
  TC = AlsoComplexType<...>, 
  TB = Really<ComplexType, TA, DontWantToTypeThisOverAndOver>
>() {
  return run<TA, TB, TC>();
}

runArgsInverted<1, MySpecialType>();
```

This isn't really the same as a generic type that falls to default, but it's a way to do what I'm trying to.  It obviously falls apart pretty quickly.